# Is it possible to copy a file from one app to ExternalFilesDirectory of another App?

Tags: android

I have Two apps **TEST1** and **TEST2**.
I have added a button in **TEST1** one app. When user press this button it should copy a file to the directory of **TEST2** app.
I tried to implement this using below code

**TEST1.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                copyAssets();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void copyAssets() throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
          String  filename="1.jpg";
            Log.d("pavan", "copyAssets: "+filename);
            in = assetManager.open(filename);
            Log.d("pavan", "copyAssets: "+getExternalFilesDir(null));
//I have given directory path of **TEST2** App.
            File outFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.TEST2/files", filename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);

}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

}

But I'm getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException:` Exception Even though the file is present.

**Exception:**

```
2019-06-05 11:46:26.934 11888-11888/com.example.test W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.TEST2/files/1.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

It may be because Android does not allow to access the directory of other Apps. 
Is there any alternative solution for this?

Comment: As per your title, Its possible to copy file from other app folder. As per your error that file is not available where you are looking for.

Comment: Error showing that your file path does not exist. correct the path.

Comment: why your error has two times **files** in `com.example.TEST2/filesfiles/1.jpg`

Comment: Yep it says file path does not exist even though the file exist , May be it doesnot allow to access directory file of another app  @Hemant Parmar .

Comment: @ Pratik Butani AndroidDev it's just a typo I edited the error for simplification.

Comment: And when I replace the path to the directory of  **TEST1** app it works pretty fine. i.e `File outFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.TEST1/files", filename);`

Comment: Have you stored file in Internal storage?

Comment: You mean  1.jpg? It is in assets of App.

Comment: I'd recommend you use a `FileProvider` for sharing files between applications: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing

Comment: @PPartisan My goal is just to modify a particular file which is stored in the directory of  **TEST2** App. there is no direct relationship between two Apps

Comment: @pa1.Shetty Used External Storage for file.

Comment: I'd still use a FileProvider. Or, I'd trigger a service in TEST2 from TEST1 that modifies the file. I wouldn't do it directly from TEST1.

Comment: @PPartisan I have no control over **TEST2** App

Comment: I tried with the file directory of different App It worked,  Maybe it had an issue with a specific app!

Answer (score 0):

All Android devices we have two file storage areas: "internal" and "external" storage. On Internal storage Files shared here are accessible by only your app not used in other application or App. So, If you want to share through External Storage and used with both (Like **TEST1** and **TEST2**) apps on same file we can access it.

For Example :

```
File outFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.TEST2/files", filename);
```

change path and used external storage path.

Comment: I tried with the file directory of different App It worked,  Maybe it had an issue with a specific app!